# Angularjs I can not get the number of forms

Tags: angularjs

as I can get the number of forms that are in a View and validate if they have filled all in AngularJS

html

```html
<form name="wizardStep2" ms-form-wizard-form novalidate>
</form>
```

controllerjs

```js
var self.forms = [];
function registerForm({self.forms.push(form);}
```

directive

```js
function msFormWizardFormDirective()
    {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            require : ['form', '^msFormWizard'],
            compile : function (tElement)
            {
                tElement.addClass('ms-form-wizard-form');

                return function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrls)
                {
                    var formCtrl = ctrls[0],
                        mv = ctrls[1];
                    mv.registerForm(formCtrl);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: I can not get the number of forms in the view

Comment: i suppose you can use javascript to collect all the forms using querySelectorAll (or something similar), which will give you an array of the forms. you can then check the length of that array, and that will tell you how many forms are in the view. Next to make sure they are all filled out you will need a function that checks that all fields have input (and perhaps have passed validation) and if they have return true.